# CountdownTimer tik issue after cancelling and start again in android

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

i have countdown timer with this code:

```
CountDownTimer CountdownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         txttime.setText( millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish(){
         timeout_stage();
         CountdownTimer.cancel();
     }
  };
```

i start it with this code:

```
 CountdownTimer.start();
```

and then i stop it by this code:

```
 CountdownTimer.cancel();
```

but after cancelling, when i start it again my CountdownTimer works but the text on the txttime is not change!! (but first time works perfectly)

how i can fix it?

Comment: I think you will probably get String resource not found Exception, becuase you are directly passing long value to TextView, which it will consider as string resouce id

Comment: What   `timeout_stage();` contain, no need to cancel timer in onFinish as it will stop it

Comment: timeout_stage();  is a function that calls an activity

Comment: @Pragnani: can you help me? plese

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Post your full code where you are starting the timer again